Can I get the cursor position from an open Google Doc using App Scripts in Chrome Browser Extension?
I have created an App script to get the Cursor position from an open Google Doc file. I am using the App script as Web Url and calling it in my Chrome Browser Extension using the fetch method. While I am able to fetch the data from the Google Doc, I am unable to get the cursor position. Everytime I trigger the App Script function from the Browser Extension, I am getting null.
Is there a way to fetch the cursor position from the Chrome Browser Extension?

Updated question with sample code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78835323/updated-can-i-get-the-cursor-position-from-an-open-google-doc-using-app-scrip/78835382#78835382

This question is similar to: [Updated]: Can I get the cursor position from an open Google Doc using App Scripts in Chrome Browser Extension?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
