[Updated]: Can I get the cursor position from an open Google Doc using App Scripts in Chrome Browser Extension?
I have created an App script to get the Cursor position from an open Google Doc file. I am using the App script as Web Url and calling it in my Chrome Browser Extension using the fetch method. While I am able to fetch the data from the Google Doc, I am unable to get the cursor position. Everytime I trigger the App Script function from the Browser Extension, I am getting null.
I am pasting a sample code for what I am trying to do. https://codepen.io/Ronak-Bhandari/pen/WNqObpP Can we get the cursor position with this approach?
If not the above, is there any other way to fetch the cursor position from the Chrome Browser Extension?
// App Script Code
function doPost(e) {
  const doc = DocumentApp.openById(JSON.parse(e.postData.contents).documentId);
  var cursor = doc.getCursor();
  Logger.log( cursor);
  if (cursor) {
    var position = cursor.getSurroundingTextOffset();
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ position: position }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } else {
    var selection = doc.getSelection();
    Logger.log('selection',selection); 
    if (selection) {
      var elements = selection.getRangeElements();
      if (elements.length > 0) {
        var element = elements[0];
        var position = element.getStartOffset();
        return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ position: position }))
                             .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
      }
    }
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ position: -1 }))
                         .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);

  }  
}

// Code in the service worker in chrome browser extension
const url = 'WEB_APP_URL_DEPLOYED_FROM_APP_SCRIPT';
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    documentId: message.documentId,
  }),
}).then((res) => res.json()).then((data) => {
  console.log(data);
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err)
});


It's impossible to use Google Apps Script, specifically the Documents Service (Class DocumentApp), to get the cursor position when the script is run using an API.
The above is because some Documents Service methods depend on data sent internally by the Google Docs web app when a function is run from the UI or the Script Editor when opened from the UI (Extensions > Apps Script).
A web application created with Google Apps Script, using doGet or doPost, can't get the cursor position when they are run by HTTP request for the above reason.
The workaround is to use web scraping.
Related

Accessing a Google Doc's content from a Chrome extension after July 2021
Get selected text
Capturing text selection in Google Docs for Chrome extension
How to update Google Docs in real-time using Chrome Extension content scripts?


All the related links shared in the answer shows how to get the selected text which is not what I am looking for. I am specifically looking for a solution where I could get the Cursor position. Is there any solution using the App script or frontend-only approach to achieve it?

@RonakBhandari Partial answers are fine. Still, there are chances that you will get the answer you are looking for. Please be patient.
